# Streaming inserts and table decorators

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to use BigQuery for realtime dashboard. I'm testing a combination of streaming inserts and table decorators.

Example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM [rt_dataset.table_xyz@1381302000000-]
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
...
```

Documentation reads as: "References data added to the table after  ..."

It seems query doesn't return realtime data (several minutes of fresh data is missing). Without table decorator query returns "fresh" data as expected.

Are there any limitations to the table decorators on tables filled with streaming inserts?

thx, sasa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the interaction between decorators and streaming. We're working on a fix.

Comment: have the issues been resolved? I am now facing this issue on streaming data

Comment: If you're seeing this still, please file a new issue.